# Determining the type of a standard jQueryUI widget

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-widget-factory

I am having trouble determining the type of a given `jQueryUI` widget instance.

The [jQueryUI documentation for the Widget Factory](http://api.jqueryui.com/jQuery.widget/) suggests two techniques. From the "Instance" section:

> The widget's instance can be retrieved from a given element using the
>   instance() method. [...]
>   If the instance() method is called on an element that is not
>   associated with the widget, undefined is returned.
>
> the :data selector can also determine whether an element has a given
>   widget bound to it.

Based on their examples, let's say I initialize a datepicker and later code checks if it is a datepicker:

```
<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"> </p>

  $(function() {
    $("#datepicker").datepicker();

    // ...
    var i = $("#datepicker").progressbar("instance"); // i is undefined as expected
    console.log(i);
    var b = $("#datepicker").is(":data('ui-datepicker')"); // b = false, not sure why
    console.log(b);
    var i2 = $("#datepicker").datepicker("instance"); // this throws an exception
    console.log(i2);
  });
```

Based on the documentation I expected the `.is` call to return true, and the last line to return the instance (not throw an exception.)

[JSFiddle is here](https://jsfiddle.net/rk4cwvhm/1/). (You will need to open the browser's console to see the logged output.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the techniques I listed above do work for many jQueryUI widgets, e.g. button, progressbar.

But datepicker is kind of weird. Looking at the DOM after a datepicker is initialized, I see the datepicker is inserted as a new element *after* the named element.

To get the datepicker widget instance I'd need to navigate the DOM starting from the named element. To check if the input field has a datepicker on it we can simply check the element for the class hasDatepicker:

```
var isDatePicker = $("#datepicker").is(".hasDatepicker");
```

This works with jQueryUI 1.11.2, and based on other SO questions it's been working since 2009. So I guess it's a reliable technique, but I'm not sure if its documented anywhere, or guaranteed for future versions.